# What is "NodeId" in chrome extension -> "chrome.debugger"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I don't know "NodeId" Means...

NodeId is source code line??

I had suffered for some time with it.. :'(

please see this url-DOM command heightlightNode link:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/dom#command-highlightNode

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it does not correspond to the source code.

It's *some* integer associated with a particular node.

You'll need to query what node it is; see other commands that take NodeId as a parameter, i.e. [`DOM.resolveNode`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM#method-resolveNode), [`DOM.getAttributes`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM#method-getAttributes) etc.

Conversely, you can find a node to get its node ID. For instance, you can get the `document` node by executing [`DOM.getDocument`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM#method-getDocument) and then, using that node, query with a selector by [`DOM.querySelector`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM#method-querySelector).

Or, if you have a JS object corresponding to the node, you can query its ID with [`DOM.requestNode`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM#method-requestNode) (use [`Runtime.evaluate`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime#method-evaluate) first to get the `RemoteObjectId`)

Basically, it's an opaque identifier that you pass to other commands.

Comment: Could you provide example how to use DOM.requestNode ?